# iOS7 delay in applying UIKeyboardAppearanceDark

Tags: ios, ios7, uikeyboard

I am seeing a strange behavior in iOS7 where I set the keyboard appearance to UIKeyboardAppearanceDark in viewDidLoad, but the keyboard will initially appear in the default (light gray) style, and then a second later switch to the dark style.

I further see this behavior in a different UIViewController when I set the keyboard appearance in a XIB file - the view loads and quickly flashes from light to dark as the view appears.

Can anyone suggest a reason for this behavior, or is this a bug in iOS7?

Comment: I filed this as a bug with apple and created a demo app that repros the issue 100%. Filed in Radar.

Comment: A consistent repro is to make a dark keyboard appear by making a UITextView first responder, then put your app in the background by pressing the home button, then restore your app. You will see your keyboard flash colors when it is restored, or at least I was able to prepare a sample app where this behavior occurred 100% of the time.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the aforementioned steps, but I do still experience this in 7.0.4 when the keyboard first displays. After initial display, the keyboard remains dark after toggling firstResponder status or backgrounding and relaunching the app.

Answer (score 0):

Set the keyboard appearance in viewWillAppear so that it's dark before the view loads.

Comment: Thanks -- in the case of the XIB file which exhibits this behavior I do not have that option. Moreover, setting it in viewDidLoad should also be sufficient since this method runs prior to the view appearing on screen.

Comment: Maybe the change in appearance is not happening on the main thread for some reason? If so you could try wrapping it in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});

Comment: using breakpoints and based on my experience with iOS I can confirm that viewDidLoad is always called on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Appearance property to Dark in Interface Builder for the UITextField in question.